If a ring has only two left ideal, then it has $1$ element
I want to prove that if a ring has only two left ideal, then it is a division ring. If $R$ has $1$, then the proof is easy but in the question it does not mention that $R$ has $1$. How can I prove it?

Please reconsider the definition of a division ring and deduce whether it could be nonunital or not.

@Amateur_Algebraist if for each element in ring there is an mult. inverse, we say that ring is a division ring.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult How to ask a good question for further guidance.

@Alistair Yes, that's almost correct (the zero shouldn't have an inverse). Now, what does it mean for $u$ to have a multiplicative inverse $v$?

The question is false as written because it does not preclude taking an abelian group with a prime number of elements and using zero multiplication for every pair of elements.  It is actually a commonly asked question, which I've added links for.  When you have exactly two right ideals, and multiplication isn't uniformly zero, then you can prove there's an identity.
